# Not a Keyword, Not In Ruby-Doc What Kind of Language Construct is include and extend?

Tags: ruby, keyword

Unless I've missed the entries, I can't find include or extend in the Ruby-Doc.org documentation or in Ruby's keyword list. I can find obj.extend but not the extend statement used in a class definition e.g.

```
# add module Foo's methods as class methods of TestClass
class TestClass
  extend Foo
end
```

or

```
# add module Foo's methods as instance methods of TestClass
class TestClass
  include Foo
end
```

As a language construct, if that's the proper term, what are include and extend and where are they defined?

It would be nice to understand just how these two statements are implemented in the Ruby language. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`extend` is an `Object` method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/extend), a convenience method for [`extend_object`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/extend_object) (more or less).

[`include` is in `Module`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/include), a wrapper around [`append_features`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/append_features).

Comment: I failed to make the self.extend associate with obj.extend in my post :).

Comment: @Dennis Believe me--the syntax, class hierarchy, and often-subtle magic make tracking down a behavior's implementation... problematic at times. It's like an adventure without the overhead of being fun.

Comment: @Dennis Although it's kinda fun, in a sick, geeky sort of way.

Comment: Dave one more question if you don't mind: Klass.private_methods shows include as one of the private_methods for Klass - could you or someone else please explain why an object Klass has access to a private method of the Module class? Does it have something to do with Module < Object subclassing?

Comment: @Dennis In Ruby, subclasses can call private methods. Some refs: [ref 1](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/ruby-access-control-are-private-and-protected-methods-only-a-guideline/), [ref 2](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/23/method-visibility-in-ruby), [ref 3](http://blog.zerosum.org/2007/11/22/ruby-method-visibility).

Answer (score 0):

include is a private method of the Module class and extend is a method in the Object class